# Jmeter Loop controller is not sending all the request given in loop count

Tags: jmeter

I have Simple scenario:

```
Thread Group - One user sign in
- HTTP Sampler for Sign in
- Loop Controller - count as 10
  - HTTP Sampler for check page
```

As per the logic, it is working fine for 1-time sign in, 10 times check the page.

But if I give the same with 10 Users sign in, 100 times from check page, it is not sending all the requests to the server.

It is sent only around 60 to 70 request for check page. other requests are not sent from the JMeter.

Server side CPU usage getting 100%, is it restricting the JMeter to send the request further?

Comment: Is the execution completed? can you share the screenshot of ViewResultsTree?

Comment: Yes, Execution completed, I have disabled listeners and executing jmeter from non GUI mode.

Comment: can you please share the TestPlan screenshot? Did you check the count of samplers sent in the .jtl/.csv file? If server is crashed you could have got 500 error, but the record for each iteration should have been entered. If Load Generator machine is overloaded, it will slow down the requests to be sent, but not completely skipping them.

Comment: As you kept Loop Controler inside an If Controller, there are high chances that the condition might have failed, hence resulting in not executing of samplers which are inside If Controller.

Comment: If controller is used to check the user signed in is true. it is true only for all the users, Also if i use less no of users it is working fine with all the request.

Comment: that is what I am saying. the condition is getting failed, i.e., user sign in is failed (for a few threads). can you share the condition that you kept in If Controller?

Comment: '${isUserSignedIn}'  == "true" 

Signin once for all users is passed, there is no repeat for signin again. once 10 users signed in, all 100 check page should be executed.

Comment: please click on the link to join the chat. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127802/discussion-between-naveen-and-devarajan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scheduler Configuration set for the duration of `600` seconds causing the test to stop before all the iterations completed, which are still running.

Removing Scheduler Configuration resolved the issue and all iterations ran.

Note: The issue is identified after long discussion in the chat with the user. so question may not contain all the details.

following are some of the configuration he did in Thread Group:

```
Duration field: ${__P(duration,600)}
Delay : ${__P{delay,0}}
```

removing them resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Scheduler Enabled in Thread Group restricted the Test running time with the argument Duration.